# Issues when referencing android library project with user defined attributes

Tags: android, reference, project

The issue is:

1. I have a project A. It runs well.
2. Then I config A as a library project. And new a project B to use it.

Then the issue comes like followings:
\res\layout\taskslist.xml:18: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'content' in package 'com.XXX'

The attribute named 'content' is defined in XML used by MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer in project A:

```
<resources>
 <declare-styleable name="MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer">
        <attr name="content" format="reference" />
        </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And the taskslist.xml looks like:

```
<com.XXX.util.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.XXX"
    ...
    my:content="@id/content">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/menuwithll" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        ... />
</com.XXX.util.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
```

Actually I look into R.java in project A. There is an attr named "content" likes:

```
public static final class attr {
     public static int content=0x7f010002;
}
```

Anyone know this issue? Thanks in advance!!!

BTW. I have tried clean project. And config project B both in "Android" and "Java build path".

Comment: Nobody know this issue? I'm trying update ADT\SDK now...

Comment: Bad news. Update ADT\SDK doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For later one's who also has this issue. It's really simple to resolve by add following code in you layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```